# Web based printing from a Django application?

Tags: django, printing, printing-web-page

Is there any recent developments in web based printing?

I know using `@media print in CSS, PDF based solution or iTextSharp` but they are not really easy (except @media print) but alignment is little tricky if receipt contains barcodes or if I have to format for A5 etc.,

Is there anything new in HTML5 which will support this?

I would like to print receipts from a Django based webapplication.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely go with `media="print"` solution for 99% of your printing needs.  For complex receipts that need absolute positioning, I've used PISA with table positioning and extremely rigid definitions for the page layout (think as if you're writing an email template).

But no, HTML5 will not save you.  It gives you nothing new with respect to printing.